# How to print different parametric-polymorphic methods in Java?

Tags: java, polymorphism, parametric-polymorphism

I have declared three methods which all have the same name "sum" in the aim to have a simple demonstration of how parametric polymorphism works, but I don't know how to call each method separately which is what I would like help with.
How can I call each method and know which one I'm calling ?

I've tried a simple `System.out.println(sum(2,3));` which returns 5 but if I set one of the numbers outside of the integer range I get an error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:
    The literal 3000000000 of type int is out of range
    at codeTester.main.main(main.java:30)
```

```java
/*
Author: Maxim Wilmot
Created:   18/04/2019
Polymorphism - Parametric
*/

package codeTester;

public class main {

    //integer between -2 147 483 648 and 2 147 483 647

    public static int sum(int a, int b) {
        return a + b;
    }

    //decimal between -3,4.10^38 and 3,4.10^38

    public static float sum(float a, float b) {
        return a + b; //
    }

    //decimal between -1,7.10^308 and 1,7.10^308

    public static double sum(double a, double b) {
        return a + b;
    }

     public static void main(String args[]) {
         System.out.println(sum(2,3)); //call a method, which one ?
     }
}
```

I want to have 3 different outputs, 1 for each method. Is that possible ? Possibly calculating different numbers for each method ?

Thanks for your help,
Max.

Comment: Yes, it is possible as long as your values are within the range for a given numeric type. Use `f` and `d` to denote `float` and `double` literals respectively.  Polymorphism will **not** take care of numeric overflowing.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply @PM77-1 , so does this mean I can't declare `sum` 3 times with different types ? If so, this wouldn't be an example of polymorphism would it ?

Comment: Yes, you absolutely can [overload](https://beginnersbook.com/2013/05/method-overloading/) your `sum()` method.  You just need to understand that only the method ***signature*** will guide the selection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Method overloading(Compile-time Polymorphism) works in java based on method signatures(i.e method name, type of arguments and order of arguments).

In your case when the literal value is 3000000000, then the value lies in long data range.

In java if you declare the literal value greater than 2 147 483 647, then you should suffix the literal with letter '**l**' or '**L**.

So pass your argument as 3000000000L or 3000000000l with another int argument then the float arguments method will be called (This will be done by upcasting of argument)

Upcasting works as below for primitive types.

byte -> short -> int -> long -> float -> double

For the below line

```
System.out.println(sum(3000000000L, 3));
```

you will get answer as

```
3.0E9
```

This output will be produced by the float argument types method.

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was looking for! :)